# How to replace a value to property file using Jenkins parameter

Tags: jenkins, echo

I have settings.properties file where I have many key values pairs as below

```
browserName=Chrome
ExecutionMode=Local
```

Am using settings.properties file to pass the input parameters to run the automation script.

Example: When I run my jenkins jobs with build parameter for example, I am entering browserName as InternetExplorer it should replace the value in the settings.properties file.

I am using the below command to achieve my target.

`echo browserName=%BROWSER_NAME% >> settings.properties`

But it is not replacing the "browserName=Chrome" instead it is adding "browserName=InternetExplorer" at the end.

Please let me know how I can replace the browserName value?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use ">>" because it will append data to the file. If you use ">" it will erase all contents of the file before inserting the echo.

So you must use the sed command. I think that the command you should run is this:

sh "sed -i 's/browserName=.*/browserName=${BROWSER_NAME}/g' settings.properties"

EDIT: Added two methods for windows

The code I sent you works only in linux. I will let you try 2 approches:

**Pure Groovy (For Windows and Linux):**

```
config = readFile "settings.properties"
newconfig = a.replaceAll("browserName=.*","browserName=${BROWSER_NAME}")
writeFile file: "settings.properties", text: "${newconfig}"
```

**Using powershell (Only in windows)**

```
newconfig=powershell(returnStdout: true, script:"cat settings.properties | %{$_ -replace 'browserName=.*','browserName=${BROWSER_NAME}'}")
writeFile file: "settings.properties", text: "${newconfig}"
```

**CAVEAT:** I don't own nor have access to a Windows' based Jenkins, so I am assuming the powershell version will work. I based this script [this](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/#targetText=Jenkins%20Pipeline%20currently%20supports%20Microsoft,of%20PowerShell%20in%20your%20Pipeline.) blog

Comment: while I entered your command it is throwing `'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file error`. Can u provide the equivalent command for windows?

Comment: I have edited my answer to included code in groovy and powershell for the pipeline. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

@mndrye 's answer is very useful, but it contains a small mistake in Groovy script and SO did not allow me to edit this mistake or report it as a comment, so I am adding the corrected version and a small explanation below.

It should be `config.replaceAll()` instead of `a.replaceAll()`. Otherwise, Jenkins gives an error like this:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: WorkflowScript
```

Corrected version;

```
config = readFile "settings.properties"
newconfig = config.replaceAll("browserName=.*","browserName=${BROWSER_NAME}")
writeFile file: "settings.properties", text: "${newconfig}"
```

To explain what's going on here;

- First, we write the content of the file to a variable
- And we change the relevant value in this variable and write it to a new variable.
- Then we rewrite this new variable into the same file. Since we do not use append here, we are actually recreating the entire file.

---

It's not exactly related to this question, but I'm adding a little tip for newbies like me who want to change a value in the property file and find their way here. If you want to run this groovy script in the declarative pipeline, but you haven't figured out how to do it yet, you can run it in the script block as follows;

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
       stage('replace') {
           steps {
               script {
                   config = readFile "/path/to/settings.properties"
                   newconfig = config.replaceAll("browserName=.*","browserName=${BROWSER_NAME}")
                   writeFile file: "/path/to/settings.properties", text: "${newconfig}"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```